# Deserialising XML to List

Tags: c#, .net, xml, list, deserialization

After many hours of trying to get a list to serialize to XML, and completing this (although I'm sure I did it very shoddily). I need to now deserialize the XML back into a list. Here is my XML file for starters.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPrograms xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Programs>
    <File-name>chrome.exe</File-name>
    <File-path>C:\Users\Shane\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe</File-path>
  </Programs>
  <Programs>
    <File-name>lol.launcher.exe</File-name>
    <File-path>C:\Riot Games\League of Legends\lol.launcher.exe</File-path>
  </Programs>
</ArrayOfPrograms>
```

And heres my config class I'm using;

```
  public class Config
{
    [XmlElement("Recipient")]
    public string recipient;
    [XmlElement("Username")]
    public string username;
    [XmlElement("Password")]
    public string password;
    [XmlElement("Serial-ID")]
    public string serialId;


[XmlElement("Email-settings")]

    public Email Emails { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("Program-List"), XmlArrayItem(typeof(Programs), ElementName = "Programs")]
    public List<Programs> Programs { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Database-settings")]
    public Database Databases { get; set; }
}

 public class Programs
{
    public string filename;
    public string filepath;
    [XmlElement("File-name")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("File-path")]
    public string Filepath { get; set; }

}
```

Can anyone give me any ideas as to which route I should be heading in? I've never dealt with deserializing into lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using (var f = File.Open("...", FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Programs>));
    List<Programs> programs = (List<Programs>)serializer.Deserialize(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's this great tool I use for that kind of thing that comes with Visual Studio called XSD

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=VS.80).aspx

Basically you point it at an XML file, then it builds your C# file. You import that into your solution and you can use the object as if it was an XML file and simply serialize or deserialize to convert between the two.

Edit:

Oh to use it, just click Start, Programs, Visual Studio (2008 or 2010), Visual Studio Tools, then the Command Prompt.

Then just head over to the folder you XML file is in and "XSD /l cs myFile.xml" for C# code that is

Comment: I've taken a look at this before : ) Thank you for the advice but because i've already struggled so much serializing the list in a manual way, for my own...curiosity's sake i'd like to try and manually do it in reverse too : P i'm crazy sometimes.

Comment: Oh, no I totally understand. It's always good to do things the hard way the first time so you appreciate what the tools do for you (and so you're not completly helpless whenever you don't have the tools)

How about Linq to XML? That would still be more work than using the tool
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Comment: judging by the way you're speaking, are we assuming here that just through hard-coding and no tools, getting XML into a list is going to be a right pain in the backside? XD

Comment: For me it's more of a once you use XSD you wouldn't go back. I wouldn't call Linq to XML a tool. It's definetly something you should try. It just lets you query the nodes in your XML file easily. Something else you could do, is just run XSD on your XML file and take a look through the C# code it produces for it.

Comment: i did that before...but it was like looking at a wall of text and i wasn't sure how to put my own variable names back into it and so on...was scary. perhaps that's why i didn't use it in the first place..

Comment: I was about to give a sample of Linq to SQL, but A.Dimo has beaten me to it. It's a handy way to put things back in a list.

Comment: alright, perhaps i'll take a look at this LINQ thing you've pointed me towards. i'll let you know how i get on. And thanks,again : D

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to XML and write code like this:

```
public class MyProgram
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}

// load data file
using ( XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader("myfilename.xml") )
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);

    var programs= from programItem in xdoc.Root.Elements()
                select new MyProgram {
                    FileName = programItem.Element("File-name").Value,
                    FilePath = programItem.Element("File-path").Value
                };

    List<MyProgram> result = programs.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are there particular namespaces i should use for this? i've never used LINQ before, but for example XmlTestReader isn't showing up as a valid option.
Edit, never mind, got it : D system.xml.linq;

Comment: System.XML, you might need to import the assembly though

Comment: The namespace is System.Xml.Linq. Linq to XML is very easy to use and you can found more info here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for deserializing xml is using XML Schema Definition Tool (Xsd.exe)

[xml schema definition tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx%20xsd.exe)

Comment: mm, i've taken a look at this before, but for learning's sake and wanting to do this...perhaps the harder way, i'd like to try and do this manually. Thanks for the advice though : )